# Check if a finite space is T0

Tags: general-topology, algorithms

Here is an algorithmic problem. The input is a positive integer $n$ and a topology on the set $[1, \dots, n]$ presented as a (randomly ordered) list of the open sets. The output is a binary value signifying whether the given topology is Kolmogorov or not. Is there a "smart" algorithm for this problem (i.e. one which reduces the implied constant and the asymptotic complexity in a mathematically meaningful way)? If in addition the input topology is guaranteed to be irreducible, are there any optimizations then?

I propose a stupid one. For each pair of distinct points (of which there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$), run through all the open sets (of which there are up to $2^n$) and check whether exactly one of them is contained in it.

Comment: Do you have any control on the size of the topology?

Comment: I tend to doubt that there's a significantly clever way to do this.

Comment: Irrelevant to the actual question, but if you're actually doing this for some reason you might improve the "$c$"  in the $O()$ by noting that "$j$, $k$ are both in $V$ or both not in $V$" is just "(j in V)==(k in V)".

Comment: In general, $O(T+n)$ is clearly the lowest possible bound (where $T$ is the number of open sets). A naive strategy would be to initialize an "adjacency" matrix of all ones, then for each open set $U$, mark all pairs $(a,b)\in U\times U^c$ as zeroes. This has the same complexity as what you have described, i.e. $O(T\cdot n)$. I suspect the bound could be improved (at least for large $T$) to something of the order $O(T+P(n))$ for a polynomial $P$, by using some clever data structure in place of the adjacency matrix, which would allow you do do the zeroing in amortized constant time.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't improve on the $n(n-1)/2$ or the $2^n$, but possibly a fairly decent Python version:

```
def pairs(n):
  return [(j,k) for j in range(n) for k  in range(n) if j<k]

def T0(tau, n):
   """Assumes tau is (a basis for) a topology on range(n) = {0,1,...,n-1}"""
  badpairs = pairs(n)
  for V in tau:
    if not badpairs:
      return True
    badpairs = [p for p in badpairs if (p[0] in V)==(p[1] in V)]
  return len(badpairs) == 0
```